# How to calculate a new mean from different means for my Systematic Review and how to calculate a new SD?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, systematic-review, sum

I am currently doing a systematic review on distal radius fractures. I want to give a mean age and sd in my systematic review. Therefor I need to calculate the mean from all the different means of the added studies.

Study 1: Included patients 30, mean 54.7 years, sd 14.1 
Study 2: Included patients 45, mean 44.6 years, sd 16.4

How to calculate a new mean from different means for my Systematic Review and how to calculate a new SD?

Comment: This can be done as described at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51622.  However, your data indicate the combined results have significantly different means. You ought to be concerned about the potential deception involved in summarizing them with a single mean and standard deviation.  It would be akin to summarizing two studies of mammals--one of canines, another of primates--by stating the mean number of legs is $3$ and the standard deviation is $1$.