# calculating mean and SE from two means and two SEs

Tags: mean

A drug trial is conducted identically in two different groups that are essentially similar at baseline. Can I obtain a joint mean and a joint SE?

For example, 
Group A has placebo group of n=224 mean of 37.6 SE of 3.3
Group B has n=236 mean of 30.9 SE of 3.0
What is their combined mean and SE and how do you do it?

Comment: Why do you want to combine Group A and Group B?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two covariance matrices](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51622/combining-two-covariance-matrices) which includes this as a special.case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Essentially you have two sample sizes, means, and standard deviations. This is enough information to compute the [pooled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance) mean and variance.

The mean will be the weighted average of the individual means. Call the combined group $X$ and let $N=N_A+N_B$. Essentially you need the sum of observations which can you write in terms of $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$.
$$
\mu_X = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i x_i = \frac{1}{N_A+N_B}(N_A\mu_A+N_B\mu_B)
$$
To compute the sample variance you do the exact same procedure, this time you need the sum of squared observations which you can write in terms of $s_A^2$ and $s_B^2$.

For $A$ (and similarly for $B$),
$$
\sum_i a_i^2 = (N_A-1)s_A^2+N_A\mu_A^2.
$$
Then we are ready to compute:
$$
\begin{align*}
s_X^2&=\frac{1}{N - 1}\left(\sum_i x_i^2 - N\mu_X^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N - 1}\left((N_A - 1)s_A^2 + N_A\mu_A^2 + (N_B - 1)s_B^2 + N_B\mu_B^2 - N\mu_X^2\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: +1. A similar answer to a generalization of this question (to any number of subgroups and arbitrary invertible functions of any moments) is given at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51622: the method continues to be *compute the sums* (of relevant powers) and then reduce those to moments.