# Can we calculate the correlation between 2 variables just from the correlations between subsets of the data?

Tags: correlation, simpsons-paradox

If I have two variables X, Y and I already have correlations for subsets of the data that that are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, can I compute the overall correlation directly from this?

It seems intuitively we should be able to just take the weighted average correlation but I’m not sure this is totally sound. I have a feeling we probably need to have  extra assumptions that the means and st.devs etc are constant among the different subsets?

Comment: The answer is a definite no, even making those extra assumptions: you can find discussions under the heading of "Simpson's Paradox," among other things.

Comment: The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51927/919 shows what it takes to combine two *covariances.* To combine correlations, you have to convert the correlations into covariances, combine the covariances, and compute the resulting correlation.  There is no algebraic simplification available.