# Incorporating the statistics of our old regression fit into our new regression

Tags: regression, missing-data

Let's assume we fit a linear regression to our data $(X_i,Y_i)_{old}$, we lose the old data points but we still have access to the coefficients and the statistics of our linear regression. New data $(X_i,Y_i)_{new}$ comes in. We want to fit a linear regression model again. What is the best method to incorporate the statistics from fit for $(X_i,Y_i)_{old}$ into our new regression?

Comment: Are you open to using a bayesian method with the priors specified by the old coefficients and standard errors?

Comment: If you have the statistics from the old regression for $n, \sum x_i, \sum x_i^2, \sum y_i, \sum y_i^2, \sum x_i y_i$ (or their equivalents of number, means, variances and covariance) then you can incorporate them into the new regression

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen If it works why not.

Comment: I second the bayesian method here, or you could use the old coefficients as starting points for the optimization but that would probably not be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Henry What is the logic behind those choices?

Comment: The simple linear regression coefficients are related to the means, variances and covariance and these statistics allow you to calculate these for the combined regression

Comment: Specific solutions along the lines indicated by @Henry appear here on CV: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6920 for instance.  Also look for threads about updating means and covariances (or moments generally) with new data -- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51622 will do -- and apply them to regression, using threads that describe how to do regression using only those moments -- such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107597.