# What method for analysis of pooled data (continuous variable)

Tags: meta-analysis, continuous-data

I sought to perform meta analysis of continuous variables

I have extracted mean and SD from multiple studies for a variable

What is the statistical method to compute a "global" mean + SD from those variables ?

Comment: Well your question already contains the answer: do a meta-analysis. So what is your question exactly?

Comment: I think you're looking for the term 'inverse variance', but there's more to it than just that. For example, are these single arm or comparative studies? Are they all using the same scale? Cochrane Handbook is a good place to start reading up on these and more.

Comment: Well Infact it seems that what I was looking for was how to calculate weighted mean. However, I still dont know how to compute multiple stadard deviation ? Is there a method to calculate "weighted" SD ?

Comment: Yes.  There's a way to combine any moments from multiple datasets (for what it's worth).  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51927/919.  It is related to the formulas for combining moments with weights, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16609/919.